# How can I create priority queue that contains my class implementation?

Tags: python, priority-queue

I got task class that I implemented, I want to insert all my tasks into priority queue, there is one in python? Do I need to implement some func inside my class to make it comparable?

Each class got priority number.

Comment: In your Data Structures class, they'll talk all about "Priority queue" this and "priority queue" that, without ever mentioning that a "priority queue" is basically just a list that is always sorted (such that if you pop an element from it, you always get the element with the highest priority in the list). This is a fairly easy thing for you to design yourself; [see the Wikipedia article on Priority Queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a priority queue in Python, see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue

Here is a simple example:

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

q = PriorityQueue()

q.put((2, 'code'))
q.put((1, 'eat'))
q.put((3, 'sleep'))

while not q.empty():
    next_item = q.get()
    print(next_item)

# Result:
#   (1, 'eat')
#   (2, 'code')
#   (3, 'sleep')
```

You can also use heapq as well.

Can't comment on your implementation without knowing more information...

Comment: My class contains priority number. Do I need to implement comparable function inside my class?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, just insert the priority number and the object into the queue. Like in the above example, the integer values are the priority numbers

Comment: Not sure, but I think the OP's question is more about making his class instances comparable wrt to the priorities in the queue.

Comment: @martineau, he mentioned he has a priority number attribute in his class, so perhaps he doesn't need to. But then he mentioned "in each class"..., I am more assuming in each instance of the same object

Comment: Perhaps you're right, since he did say "each class got priority number"  which would mean that attribute could be used in conjunction with the `PriorityQueue` built-in.

Comment: Actually this solution works almost well for me. But I have noticed that I can not insert to "tasks" that have the same priority, what can I do in that case?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "tasks"....but usually priority queues will treat objects with the same priority in the order they were inserted in